# Two html forms on one page; Can only select second form fields with tab

Tags: html, forms

I have a a page with two forms on it. I can only click inside the input boxes of one form. For the other form, I can select the input boxes but only if I use tab. Is there anyway I can fix this? The site is http://login.peakperformancecct.com/. Just for reference, here is my code:

```
<div class="login">
        <h1>Email Login</h1>
        <form name="emaillogin" id="loginform" action="http://www.nspirelab.com:2095/login" method="POST">
            <p>
                <label for="user">Email Address<br />
                <input class="input" id="user" name="user" type="text" value="" size="20" /></label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="pass">Password<br />
                <input id="pass" name="pass" class="input" type="password" size="20" /></label>
            </p>
            <p class="submit">
                <input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="Log In" />
            </p>
        </form>
</div>
<div class="login">
    <h1>Site Login</h1>
    <form name="sitelogin" id="loginform" action="http://peakperformancecct.com/wp-login.php" method="post">                
        <p>
            <label for="user">Username<br />
            <input class="input" type="text" name="log" id="log" value="" size="20" /></label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="pass">Password<br />
            <input class="input" type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd" size="20" /></label>
            </p>
        <p class="submit">  
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log In" class="button-primary" />
        </p>
    </form> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Validate, validate, validate](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Flogin.peakperformancecct.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).

Your labels in the second form are `for` the inputs in the first form.

Clicking on the label sends the focus to the input with which it is associated

(Since the inputs are inside the labels, so you can't click on the input without clicking on the label too).